# How to share a .skin theme file between themes in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, themes

We have a legacy app with multiple asp.net themes.  Each theme have a .skin file.  Each skin file is almost identical except for some things.  The files share a lot of similarities.  Is it possible to share a common .skin file across themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible, skins are by design contained within a theme:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1268733.aspx/1

Answer (score 5):

It is possible by creating a base theme skin file somewhere and then using an include in the specific theme skin files.

For instance, you would define all your controls in baseTheme.skin and put it somewhere on your server.  Then, in your specific theme file (theme.skin), you would do an include back to your base.

```
<!-- #include file="../themeBase.skin" -->
```

Comment: +1. The syntax is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3207d0e3(v=vs.85).aspx) and works in .skin files.